# Custom CSS elements overwriting each other

Tags: css

I added the following custom CSS to my wordpress theme to change the location of the menu on the mobile version of the site:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.mob-nav {
top: 25% !important;
}
```

I then added this code to adjust the margins on the logo for the full desktop version of the website:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.right-menu .logo img {
margin-top: -15px !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.right-menu .logo img {
margin-bottom: -5px !important;
}
```

When I added the second bit of code it overwrites the CSS I added for the menu. I know they're conflicting somehow but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: syntax error ... check your `{ }`

Comment: Please use better editors, they can save lot of your time.

Comment: Better editors? I just pulled the code from Chrome Developer and added it to the custom CSS field in my theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) .mob-nav { top: 50% !important; }
@media (min-width: 992px)
{
 .right-menu .logo img
 { 
  margin-top: -15px !important; 
 }
 }

@media (min-width: 768px) 
{ .right-menu .logo img
{ 
   margin-top:0px !important;
   margin-bottom: -5px !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

The margins are correct with your code the but the .mob-nav element is still be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, I change the top portion of your code to:

```
    @media (max-width: 767px)
    {
    .mob-nav 
    { 
    top: 25% !important; 
    }
    }
```

I guess it was missing a { before .mob-nav

Thanks for the help!